# Mailchimp list post members

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am testing Mailchimp API 3.0 to add some members to a specific list.

The post request to add new members works great. But if I go to MailChimp website and go to list tab I don't see members in list and I don't send campaign and after again click on list tab I see them .

Why is this happening, if list have members?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed some lag between the creating of a record through MailChimp's API and when it appears in the UI. if you are able to GET the resource you just created through the API though it exists on the list.

Comment: I use mailchimp in .net c#

Comment: Understood. : ) There still might be a little bit of lag between the when you post a new member to when it shows up in the UI.